# Animation end does not smoothly transition to new image

Tags: android, android-animation

I have an image view that shows an up/down arrow depending on the state of the `BottomSheet` and I am trying to animate the arrow so that it looks nicer but at the end of the animation it does not smoothly transition to the new image. I see the old image for like a millisecond until it switches to the updated one.

here is my code

```
private val bottomSheetCallback = object:BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback(){
        override fun onSlide(p0: View, p1: Float) {}

        /**
         * Listen to state changes of the bottom sheet
         */
        @SuppressLint("SwitchIntDef")
        override fun onStateChanged(p0: View, state: Int) {
            when(state){
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> startRotateAnimation()
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> startRotateAnimation()
            }
        }

        private fun startRotateAnimation(){
            val rotateAnimation:RotateAnimation = RotateAnimation(0f,180f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f)
            rotateAnimation.duration = 500
            rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(object : Animation.AnimationListener {

                override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animation?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationRepeat(animation: Animation?) {
                }

                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animation?) {
                    when(_scannedBarcodesList.state){
                        BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED -> expand.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_24px)
                        BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED -> expand.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_24px)
                    }
                }
            })
            expand.startAnimation(rotateAnimation)
        }
    }
```

I am trying to rotate the image 180 degrees (so up arrow points down for example) and then at the end of the animation actually switch the image view to the down arrow but like I said the animation seems to end before the image changes showing the up arrow for a millisecond so it looks bad.

How can I get rid of the animation ending before the image gets switched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are changing the image when the animation ends that causing jank in UI.

try this way

```
public static void rotateView(ImageView iv, int stateOfBottomSheet){
        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation;
        if(stateOfBottomSheet == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED){
            rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(180.0f, 0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        }else {
            rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(0.0f,180.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        }
        rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(0);
        rotateAnimation.setDuration(300);
        rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        iv.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
    }
```

Comment: Only problem with this is that on device rotation the the image resets to its default state so you end up with a scenario where the bottom sheet is already expanded but the arrow is showing the up direction like it needs to be expanded again. Which is why I changed the image itself when the animation ends

Comment: @tyczj The key point in this answer is `rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);` which allows the end result of the animation to persist so it doesn't flip back. I think that you can set to fill after _and_ change the image at the end of animation. You could also check the status of the bottom sheet on rotation and set the appropriate image upon recreation of the activity/fragment.

Comment: @Cheticamp yeah I understand I was just pointing out that adding that in does not completely fix the problem, just shifts an issue somewhere else that also needs to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

I will place to arrows (vector drawables) into the top of the bottom sheet and try to rotate them 180° clockwise and counter-clockwise

```
BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(mBottomSheet);

        // change the state of the bottom sheet
        bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);

        // set callback for changes
        bottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
                // Called every time when the bottom sheet changes its state.
            }

            @Override
            public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
                if (isAdded()) {
                    animateBottomSheetArrows(slideOffset);
                }
            }
        });
```

here is animateBottomSheetArrows method

```
  private void animateBottomSheetArrows(float slideOffset) {
            // Animate counter-clockwise
            mLeftArrow.setRotation(slideOffset * -180);
            // Animate clockwise
            mRightArrow.setRotation(slideOffset * 180);
        }
```

This animation is fairly simple. We just pass our slideOffset value to animateBottomSheetArrows method and use it to set the rotation value of our images.